# Attempting to do emotion tagging

Tags: python, data-science, sentiment-analysis

I'm currently working on a sentiment analysis.

```
from transformers import pipeline

sent_pipeline=pipeline('sentiment-analysis')
```

This are my codes and the error its giving me is:

> Failed to import transformers.models.gpt2.modeling_gpt2 because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
> add_code_sample_docstrings() got an unexpected keyword argument 'real_checkpoint'

I have tried installing/upgrading transformers and it still couldn't work

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you're using a version of python compatible with the software!

Comment: My python version is 3.10.9 pytorch version 1.12.1 tensorflow 2.14.0